# Why a mesh deforms when I apply Curve modifier?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I need to move a mesh along a curve. I followed the steps in this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4z0AD_iXr1I  because is very similiar to what I want to do, but when I apply the curve modifier my mesh deforms. These are the screenshots before and after:

[image: Before applying curve modifier]

[image: After applying curve modifier]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you actually want to move an object along a curve, try [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8356/599). As for the deformation, it seems like your object might be positioned strangely, but it's hard to say. Could you upload your .blend?

Comment: Hi! Yes, my .blend is here: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/28260

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems:

- The *origins* of the curve and the object need to be in the same place.
- The cylinder is rotated slightly, try rotating it so that it is horizontal.
- The curve is scaled and rotated. You can fix this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Rotation & Scale* with the curve selected.

**Result:**

[image]