# Getting a flat, thin, long, cube (ribbon) to follow Beizer curve?

Tags: modifiers, objects, workflow, bezier-curves

How do I make a ribbon follow a Beizer curve? I've found ways to make a round pipe out of a curve but not a flat ribbon.
[image: screen shot of curve and ribbon]

Comment: Use Curve modifier with [setting up your ribbon](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8396/why-a-mesh-deforms-when-i-apply-curve-modifier) correctly. Also note that the ribbon should be subdivided enough so to be able being curved

Comment: @MrZak next time you have an answer to something, post it! There's not reason to let someone else get all the rep for your technique!

Comment: @TARDISMaker I wanted to mark it as a duplicate because I was sure it is. Hence I thought there's no reason to answer here.

Comment: @MrZak I don't quite think that's a duplicate. There's some good information in gandalf3's answer though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would make the curve flat by not bending a mesh to fit it, but "beveling" the curve (adding thickness).

1. Add a BezierCircle (in addition to the curve you already have)
2. In edit mode convert the handle type to *Vector* (super quick way <kbd>V</kbd>,<kbd>V</kbd>), that will make it a square.
3. Rotate it 45° along the Z axis (just to make it straight along an axis).
4. Scale the square along the X axis, to make it a thin ribbon.
5. (Last step) On your other curve object set the *Bevel Object* to be the "BezierCircle" you added in step one.

[image: animated gif]

Comment: @David smart solution!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27250/discussion-on-answer-by-david-getting-a-flat-thin-long-cube-ribbon-to-follo).

Answer (score 6):

Place an object so its origin point is located in the same position as a curve's origin point.

[image]

Subdivide the object as many times you like (being in *Edit Mode* press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and scroll the mouse wheel to increase the number of cuts or just type the number from your numerical keyboard).

[image]

Add a ***Curve Modifier*** to the object. In a window under *Object:* type the name of your curve.

[image]

Enable ***Display modifier in Edit Mode*** option to easy adjust the lenght of an object and make it fit the curve perfectly. It is very handy as you may change the object's parameters and see how it looks placed on a curve in the same time.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

To follow up with images from Mr Zak's comment, which specified the answer:

First make sure you have enough subdivisions to deform the "cube" along the curve (loop cut and slide - Ctrl + R, is a quick way to achieve this).
[image: Subdivisions]

Then add a curve modifier and set the axis up correctly:
[image: Curve Modifier]