# Cover the Curve Bezier with a Plane. It's impossible to duplicate it and R it

Tags: bezier-curves

I did a Curve Bezier and I wrap with a Plane to make a ribbon.
When I try to copy it and rotate the ribbon(plane) is undone.

After the Curve Bezier. I did: Modifier / curve / object. Curve Bezier

In this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTVgyjh4Yro  7:25
it's possible to copy the ribbon.

Thanks a lot.
[image]

Comment: [Alternative ways](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/36103/2217) to make the ribbon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Duplicate it you should have **both** objects selected the **Plane** and the  **Curve**, but in order to make it successfully the active object when you dublicate should be the **Curve**.

*Your problem is that you selected only the plane when duplicating*

Comment: Hi @Meri :) Please consider that this is not a forum. If Igor solved your issue, you should **accept the answer** for future visitors. Also accepting is the best way to say "Thank you". Please see the tour: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour.