# Running and walking animation?

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging, camera

I'm new to blender and l have a question recently l started making a 3d model well l tried to recreate a model from Star Wars The Old Republic well I'm trying to recreate this guy in blender:[image]

and my goal is to learn animation and be a successful 3D artist because it's my very great dream to be 3d artist and here is the progress with the model : [image]

And please help if someone can because l can't figure out how l can create walking animation and running animation too and how to make the camera to rooted around the model and also when you are done with the animation how you can save it as a video and please help because it's my long dream to be a great 3D artist and l just really want to known and please someone can please help !

P.S Sorry for the bad English I'm a Lithuanian

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE, what your're asking is a tutorial request which is off-topic here, sorry. The most things are already answered see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3736/how-should-an-animated-character-be-moved-while-repeating-a-walk-cycle  and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8356/camera-angle-should-follow-path-angle/8360#8360

Comment: l forgot to mention a nother question how you can create the flowing cape animation ?

Comment: Currently there are multiple questions being asked here, it would be better to split the different requests into separate questions (if the questions haven't already been asked by other users on this site)

Comment: @Paulius the flowing cape can be done with the cloth simulator.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create an animation such as walking you need to do some 'Rigging'.
There are plenty of tutorials on this. Try to search on Youtube for things such as 'Blender character rigging' and you should get a lot of good results. Don't think about rigging until you've finished your model, though. You must make sure you model correctly. As you're new to Blender you will end up modeling in a difficult way, which is what most people do.

I suggest you download a low poly character model and practice on that. But I highly recommend you look at many different tutorials on character modeling, rigging and topology; the latter is very important. It also makes the Rigging process a lot easier. It'll take time but you've got to be willing to learn everything there is to know, if you want to be a good CG artist; it's a tough business.

Sites like [Blenderguru](http://blenderguru.com) and [Blender Cookie](http://cgcookie.com/blender/) are a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you guys for the great advices and again thank you and l'll get started working  on the model right away and l'm almost done with the mask