# how to make an object follow a curve with the same speed as another animated object

Tags: animation, scripting, constraints, path

Say I have an object which has an animation.

[image: (I turned on the motion path to make it more clear)]

I have another object which is constrained to a curve. I want it to follow the curve BUT I want it to do it at the same speed as the animated object.

[image]

here I am manually moving the object to show what I mean. I want the cube to move along the path, but with the same variations in speed that the moving camera has.

Doing this will essentially let me deform a motion path like you would do with a mesh.
I don't know much about coding so if the answer includes writing some kind of script, I would really appreciate it if you gave an example :)

EDIT: batFINGER phrased it well in the comments: "for every frame if Free object moves d units, the path object will move d along the curve"

Also, preferably I would also like to do this live in blender.

Comment: To clarify, for every frame if Free object moves `d` units, the path object will move `d` along the curve?  Doing it live, is do-able but tricky. Baking it post animation is simpler, _eg_ using a slow empty one frame behind the camera, `d` is the distance between.  Knowing  the length of the curve, offset the path object.

Comment: ... noticing your last comment, given you have an animation for the camera,, the empty can be animated via same animation offset via NLA.  Please [edit] any extra details into the question.  See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159719/15543 re using array / curve modifiers to give curve dimension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bake the displacement.**

[image]

Given

> I used a gltf camera path which I exported from a video game, so Its
> just a keyframe animation

Here is a quick baking script,

Whenever the animation of the camera has been changed, run the script to bake some simple physics.

- Set scene to first frame of action save the location as previous location
- For each frame of camera action
- Calculate the distance from frame location to previous location and store
- Set the location as previous.

From the data bake in 3 animations on custom properties

- "speed"  The amount of distance travelled that frame
- "disp" The accumulative displacement
- "offset" The frame displacement as a fraction of total
- The values of the 3 are keyframed into the camera action
- The cube in GIF has a follow path constraint to circle, the relative offset is being driven by cameras custom property "offset" added by script. [image]
  Baked in graph editor
  [image]

Here is a test script, assuming the animated object is scene camera, and it is animated by active action

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
cam = scene.camera
action = cam.animation_data.action
frames = np.arange(*action.frame_range)

def gloc(ob):
    return ob.matrix_world.to_translation()



locs = []
scene.frame_set(frames[0])
ploc = gloc(cam)
for f in frames:
    print(f)
    scene.frame_set(f)
    loc = gloc(cam)
    s = (loc - ploc).length
    locs.append(s)
    ploc = loc


def flatten(a, b):
    c = np.empty((a.size + b.size,), dtype=b.dtype)
    c[0::2] = a
    c[1::2] = b
    return c

def fcurve(fcurves, datapath, data):
    cam[datapath] = 0.0
    fc = fcurves.find(datapath)
    if fc:
        fcurves.remove(fc)
    fc = fcurves.new(datapath)
    fc.data_path = f'["{datapath}"]'
    fc.keyframe_points.add(len(frames))

    fc.keyframe_points.foreach_set(
            "co",
            flatten(frames, data)
            )
    fc.convert_to_samples(*action.frame_range)           

# per frame speed    
speed = np.array(locs)
fcurve(action.fcurves, "speed", speed)

# displacement
disp = np.cumsum(speed)
fcurve(action.fcurves, "disp", disp)
# Offset of total displacement

offset = disp / disp[-1]

fcurve(action.fcurves, "offset", offset)
```

**Note**, GIFs shown are not  moving two objects same distance each frame, rather the same offset fraction along their asscociated paths per frame.  To make it 1:1 distance would require [calculating the length of the constraint curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159719/15543)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: sorry it looks like I misunderstood your question as your object A follows a curve path. Anyway I leave my original answer.

Let's say the cone is the object A that goes straight ahead and the cube is the object B that is following a curve.

First, you can do it with ***Curve*** modifier and ***Copy Location*** constraint:

[image]

- Create a plane, give it a *Curve* modifier (with the curve as *Object*) and a *Copy Location* constraint (with the cone as *Target*)
- Select the cube, shift select the plane, select 3 vertices of the plane and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to parent the cube to the plane vertices
- Animate the cone, the plane will go along the curve and the cube will follow the plane

[image]

You can also do it with ***Drivers***:

Give your cube a *Follow Path* constraint, enable its *Follow Curve* option, right click on *Offset* value and choose *Add Driver*:

[image]

In the pop-up panel, choose the object the cube is supposed to follow, in *Expression* choose a variable, here *-40 -50 (-0 is here so that it begins at the right position), you can right click on *Offset* to *Open Drivers Editor*, press <kbd>V</kbd> to make a linear curve, rotate the curve, test the animation:

[image]

Here is what it gives for me:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried using the drivers, and this is what I got: https://imgur.com/i2VVqFV  . The problem is I want it to only progress along the path in one direction. Linking the offset value to the axis-value of object A means it depends on how far away object A is from the origin. Is there some kind of way or expression I can transfer the free movements of object A into the offset value of the constrained object?

Comment: oh ok you're right I completely missed that aspect, it may be doable with script, I hope someone will answer. Btw how do you move your object A? If you make it move along a curve it will make things easier but it looks like not...

Comment: I used a gltf camera path which I exported from a video game, so Its just a keyframe animation