# How do I start motion on a curve on a later frame?

Tags: bezier-curves, keyframes, parent

I have my camera parented to a curve using "Follow Path", and it travels just right, I just need it to start moving on a much later frame, not frame 1. I tried to key frame the Evaluation Time but I get the error message seen below.

[image: Here is the scene. I typed in "1" for the Evaluation Time.]
*Here is the scene. I typed in "1" for the Evaluation Time.*

[image: Report: Error. F-Curve with path 'eval_time{0}' cannot be keyframed, ensure that it is not locked or sampled, and try removing F-Modifiers]
*I pressed "I" over the Evaluation Time and got this -- Report: Error. F-Curve with path 'eval_time{0}' cannot be keyframed, ensure that it is not locked or sampled, and try removing F-Modifiers*

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21041/change-start-time-of-camera-following-a-path/21046#21046

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty **easy**... *once you know what you're doing.*

1. *Switch* to the ***graph editor***.
2. **Expand** the *"bezierCurve"* object, and **select** *"EvaluationTime"*.
3. **Press <kbd>n</kbd>** and scroll down to the *"modifiers"* section.
4. On the *"generator"* modifier, **edit** the *"coefficient for polynomial 'y'"*
5. **Lowering** this value will make the animation start on a *later frame*. You can see this by looking at where the line intersects the *0* point.

[image]

You can edit the path using "restrict frame range". Simply set the start and end frame, then use the in and out to control the easing.

Comment: This is almost perfect! I got the camera moving at frame 2291 but I now realize I want it to ease in and ease out. How do I do that?

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. One (probably the easiest) is by using the "restric frame range" feature.

Comment: Simply click it, set the beginning and end time of the move, then change the ease values. You should check out this link for more details on other methods and in depth explanation. http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21046/20428

Answer (score 0):

How you'd do this depends on what sort of control you need over the object's motion along the path.

The method suggested in [Uncle Snail](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/20428/uncle-snail)'s [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50623/41126) may work for you. But if you want to directly keyframe that motion with detailed control over interpolation, there's an easy option: just delete the generator. (Click on the 'X' next to the Generator header, visible in the screenshot in that answer.)

Then, you'll be able to keyframe the path's Evaluation Time and manipulate the curves in the graph editor.