# Delayed Follow Path

Tags: animation, constraints, keyframes

I want an object to follow a path but only start following that path after a certain time. For example, a rocket waiting on a launch pad then it follows a path into the sky. I do not want to make two separate animations then putting that together. Thanks!

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50616/how-do-i-start-motion-on-a-curve-on-a-later-frame and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21041/change-start-time-of-camera-following-a-path/21046#21046

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the "Follow path" constraint, set it to "Fixed Position" and add a keyframe to the offset value (right click it) as seen in this GIF:

[image]