# How to add bezier curves (start and end) to a 'follow path' animation?

Tags: animation, path, bezier-curves, graph-editor

I added an object to a curve as a follow path animation but the animation seems too linear, I can only change the parameters of the curve as I see, how can I give it a proper start and end? (like a soft bezier curve)?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that there is an easier way than this as I am still learning Blender --

Use the offset on the Follow Path Modifier instead of Animate Path to control the movement. Then in the Graph Editor for the object you are controlling on the path you will have a curve to work with. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it .

**Don't press the animate path button** on the Animate Path constraint.

[image]
Then animate the Offset using keyframes and bezier interpolation.

Read: [Change start time of camera following a path?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21041/change-start-time-of-camera-following-a-path/21046#21046)