# Can I create Walk throughs from external designs

Tags: animation

Can I create a design(house) using Sketchup, import the design into Blender and then create a walk through presentation using Blender?

Regards,
Dion

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive about what you mean by a *walk through* ?

Comment: Parent the camera to a curve. Then animate the movement of the camera following the shape of the curve. Please see this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8356/camera-angle-should-follow-path-angle

Comment: you could make it interactive with the game engine.

Comment: By walk trhough I mean a virtual tour of the inside of the house in a 3d environment

Answer (score 1):

You may try to press shift+f in the viewport, and then tab to turn on gravity, this let's you walk around scene using WSAD and space for jump. Additionally, you have "height" and "jump height" settings in bottom left part of preferences/input tab [pref_pan http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=86222](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=86222)