# Camera rotates on Z angle (rolls) during following spline

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

I have made an intricate path for my camera to follow based on the instructions in [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8356/camera-angle-should-follow-path-angle), and it almost works fine, except that the camera rolls for apparently no reason. Is there any way to counter this?

The path:
[image]
The camera is placed exactly at the location of the first point of the curve, that is also the curve origin. The camera faces exactly the way the curve will start.

[image]
The camera is parented to the curve.

[image]
The curve is 3D, and the evaluation is already keyframed.

[image]
When the animation starts, the camera faces forward and is not tilted.

[image]
[image]

As the animation progresses, the camera always faces forward, but it start rolling left and right.
Is there a way to keep it straight during the whole animation? Or any way to control the tilt?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got at least two options to control the roll of your camera as it follows the path.

1. Any curve has not only a longitudinal direction, but also a twist, interpolated between its control points. You can see it  by looking at the changing plane of the arrows which constitute the curve's Normal display. In edit mode, you can modify the twist by selecting control points, and after hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, winding the mouse around the selection. The camera will follow the twist.
2. For better and perhaps more intuitive control of the roll of your camera between control points, you can create an empty, and assign a 'Locked Track' constraint to the camera, with Y as the direction, and the empty as the target.
   The empty then becomes a handle for the up direction of the camera,(which now ignores the twist of the path). How you control the empty is up to you.You can animate it, leave it stationary a long way off, make it follow the path too, so it's always easy to reach... all sorts.

Comment: Thank you, the first solution seemed to work, although it is hard for me to guess why is the 0 degree tilt, that is the default for all the nodes, caused that much of a roll.

Comment: I't not clear from the documentation what the Curve>Twist options 'Tangent' and 'Minimum' are.. maybe someone can draw us a picture :)